# how to keep my node app running even when there is an error up on request

Tags: node.js, request

I am fetching some data using intervals, sometimes i have multiple formats of data and i need to send request more than multiple times. Sometimes it gives error, like `CONN CLOSED` or `ECONNRESET`, but this is not the problem. My nodejs app stops executing when even it gets 1 error, but im dealing with 10s of requests, so that 1 error is not big problem for me and i want to keep my app running. How can I achieve this, I tried `try catch` but it didn't work as well. At the bottom you can see one of the logs as an example.

```
const request = require('request')
var fs = require('fs')
// Request URL

var url = 'url.net';

i = 0

async function sender(){
  try {
    request(url, (error, response, body)=>{

          // Printing the error if occurred
        if(error) console.log(error)

          // Printing status code
        console.log(response.statusCode + '-'.repeat(i));
        i++
        if(i == 20){
          i = 0
        }
          // Printing body
    });
  }
  catch (e) {

  }

}
```

Here is how the program stops executing

```
StatusCode 200 receiving data
StatusCode 200 receiving data
StatusCode 200 receiving data

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\sendingReq\send.js:18
        console.log(response.statusCode + '-'.repeat(i));
                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'statusCode')
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\sendingReq\send.js:18:30)
    at self.callback (C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\sendingReq\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Request.onRequestError (C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\sendingReq\node_modules\request\request.js:877:8)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:494:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

Node.js v18.12.1
```

Comment: Since it's `response` that is undefined, your `try` would need to be in the same function where you attempted to do `response.statusCode`.  In other words, in that arrow function.  Put the `try` before your `if(error)` statement.  `response?.statusCode` is another way to dodge the exception.  But I have to ask, why not just fix your bug?

Comment: the bug has to occur. it is a server side thing. i will try that

Comment: The problem is not all errors have a .statusCode.  Your code assumes it does, but an ECONNRESET is not an HTTP error.  Also try/catch does NOTHING with a callback-type thing (like how you're calling `request`)  If you use the async version (where you `await request...`) then you can catch errors with try/catch.

Comment: thank you for this, i totally missed that. I have one quick question, if i send too many requests, and if my client cannot handle that, that has to do with my own bandwith and not request module, right ? @Joe